# Storing request URL in spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have spring boot application (frontend[using spring boot and thymeleaf] and backend[spring boot] separated) which uses authorization server.
The frontend is authenticated and authorized by the auth server with a token. This token is used by the frontend to communicated to the backend.

The auth server when authenticating and authorizing the frontend **ALWAYS** forwards the request to the frontend dashboard with a token.
This is main issue here, I don't have control over the auth server. How can I store the request URL (received by the frontend)
before redirecting the request to the auth server authorization so that I can redirect the user to the correct URL and not always to the dashboard of the application.

[image]

**Is there any way in spring boot to store the URL** (step 1) and later when token is received from the auth server (step 3), use this token to communicate to the backend instead of always redirecting to the dashboard.

Please note as auth server out of my reach, I cannot make any changes to it. So when the auth server authorizes the request, it changes the url used by the user and always redirect to the dashboard.

Comment: Please let me know if you need any other information

Comment: when you say "token" what do you mean, there are several token types

Comment: jwt access token

Comment: JWT access tokens should not be handed out to browsers.

Comment: The token is given to the frontend to communicate with the backend. There is no token given to the backend and browser.

Comment: What? Your sentance makes no sence.

Comment: When the user enters credentials in the login form and submits, the request goes to the frontend, the frontend then redirects the request to auth server, once user is authenticated auth server redirect the request back to the frontend with access token. This access token is used by the frontend to communicate with the backend (to perform any CRUD operations needed). All the requests from the frontend must access token (in header with Bearer type access token) to communicate with backend.

Comment: Hi Syed, 
Your statement is a bit confusing - "the request goes to the front end (which essentially loads in the browser), and the front end then redirects the request to the auth server". What is your IDP (Keycloak/Cognito)? and are you using the Rest APIs that the IDP provides to generate the token?

Comment: Can you provide the code from frontend app on how are you calling the auth server?

Answer (score 1):

I assuming you want to capture the URL in **1** to redirect after **5** completes instead of your standard page?

In spring you can do this with spring security with `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/public-pages/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()  // All other URLz req authentication
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")  // <- your login page
                .successHandler(savedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler())  // this saves the previous url
                .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    public SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler savedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
        SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler authSuccessHandler = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        authSuccessHandler.setTargetUrlParameter("redirectTo");
        return authSuccessHandler;
    }
}
```

Comment: The frontend does not have login form, it just forwards the request to the auth server, the auth server dispalys the login form for the user and authenticates. In the above solution I cannot use the .formLogin().successHandler(). There are just few antMatchers() in the frontend security class.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the default oauth2 behavior like this? I don't know if I understand it correctly. Suppose:

Browser access to http://client1.hiboot.cn:8081/test/index After authorized login, it will still return to http://client1.hiboot.cn:8081/test/index by default Dex

If you need to call the back-end service through token  or redirect to other page before returning to /test/index, you can implement AuthenticationSuccessHandler

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain defaultFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .oauth2Login(c -> c.successHandler(new CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler()))
            .authorizeHttpRequests(c -> c.anyRequest().authenticated())
            .build();
}

static class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //take token from authentication and invoke backend
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }
}
```

I'm using springboot3.1.5

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:
firstly i would capture the url, and put it in the user session in the key `lastRequestUrl`

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import java.io.IOException;

public class UrlCaptureFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpSession session = req.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("lastRequestUrl", req.getRequestURL().toString());
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

then you can redirect to the capture url, After receiving the token from the auth server, you can retrieve the stored URL from the user's session `session.getAttribute("lastRequestUrl")` retrieves the stored URL and `new RedirectView(lastRequestUrl)` creates a view that redirects to this URL

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView;

@RestController
public class RedirectController {

    @GetMapping("/redirect")
    public RedirectView redirectToLastRequestUrl(HttpSession session) {
        String lastRequestUrl = (String) session.getAttribute("lastRequestUrl");
        return new RedirectView(lastRequestUrl);
    }
}
```

last step configure the application to use the custom filter `new UrlCaptureFilter()` creates an instance of the custom filter and `registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*")` specifies that the filter should apply to all URL

```
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class FilterConfig {

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<UrlCaptureFilter> urlCaptureFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean<UrlCaptureFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
        registrationBean.setFilter(new UrlCaptureFilter());
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
        return registrationBean;
    }
}
```

after all that you could also have problems of 302 redirects which must be resolved.
to resolve this i would personally i made a new `/.dir` in the `root/java/name_project/application/request` and i'm using this security configuration:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                 .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/some_other_url/**")).anonymous());
         http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                 .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/some_url/**")).anonymous());
http.csrf(csrf ->
                csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers(
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/some_other_url/***")));
         http.csrf(csrf ->
                 csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers(
                         new AntPathRequestMatcher("/some_url/***")));
    
    super.configure(http);
    }
}
```

i hope this could help if it does not i may have another solution

Comment: you could specify a `@Bean` using the `AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails` which can be useful when working with endpoints